# Number of different trees with 8 nodes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

> The number of  $\color{red}{\text{ different trees with 8 nodes}}$  is:

1. $256$
2. $255$
3. $248$
4. $\color{blue}{\text{None of these}}$

---

My attempt:

Since, question does not about order of tree, so I assume that combinations of possible tree with connected. i.e,$\color{green}{\text{ $N^{N-2}=8^6$ should be answer.}}$

> But, somewhere it explained as :
>
> The number of trees with $n$ nodes is given by formula
>
> $\color{#FF033E}{\text{$2^n - n  = 2^8-8=256-8=248$}}$

Can you explain it, please?

Comment: Well, are you talking about labeled tree or unlabeled tree? (But for both there is no formula like $2^n-n$.)

Comment: @CaveJohnson, yes. AFAIK, different trees means labeled, right?

Comment: Check in your source what is meant by a "tree". Maybe they had a "search tree" in mind.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, well, there should use [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)  and answer will be $\color{blue}{\text{$1430$}}$, rt?